# How to implement security system to keep IP addresses and browser history in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

To implement the security system in my application. I want to keep the history of visitors and users IP addresses and browser identity. In my application, visitors are those who do not sign up with my application and can access certain parts of my application.

What is the best way to implement it in laravel 5? Is there method like boot() which could serve my requirement.

Comment: There is no specific way for doing this in all versions of laravel that i know. You can put your code in a Middleware

Comment: You can also use a package. I found these for you http://packalyst.com/s/visitor, this particular one is close to what you are looking for http://packalyst.com/packages/package/pragmarx/tracker

Comment: @Hassan if you're happy with my answer below, you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [middleware](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-middleware-filter-style).

1. Create middleware:

```bash
artisan make:middleware StoreUserInfo
```

This command will create class `App\Http\Middleware\StoreUserInfo`

2. Edit StoreUserInfo class:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use DB;
use Session;

class StoreUserInfo
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!Session::get('user-info-stored')) {

            // save IP address and browser to DB

            // set session flag to prevent DB duplicates
            Session::put('user-info-stored', true);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

---

Keep in mind that your software should be privacy-compliant. In some countries like Germany it's illegal to store user's IP address. Read more: https://github.com/piwik/piwik/issues/692

Comment: I liked your answer. But not tested it yet. I have some questions if you know them.
With a proper consent in terms and conditions, still it would be illegal? Can we store hashes instead of plain IP. Because the purpose is completely to provide additive security... Do you have any such information?

Comment: @HassanSaqib For sure you can store hashes of IP adresses. Also, you can store not whole IP address, but only part of it, e.g. instead of ``192.160.1.123`` put in DB ``192.160.0.0``.